# how check today's date for particular date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I want to check today's date with some other date which is in `String`, if both are equals then need to perform some tasks.

I tried `date1 < date2` but it is comparing date, I want equal check

Comment: Please do not use date formatters for comparing dates. The selected answer is wrong (as are most of the others). Date formatters should only be used for displaying dates to the user. I have added an answer that uses a built in `Calendar` function to do this for you.

Comment: I want compare String which has date `eg. 10.10.2010` with today's date which is in date format so I used above code

Comment: In that case you should use a date formatted to turn the string into a Date. And then use the calendar function to compare it with another Date. Don’t compare dates as strings.

Comment: Where does the string come from that you are using? How are you getting that string?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use below code to check equal dates

```
func getCurrentDate() -> String {

    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    let result = formatter.string(from: date)

    print(result)
    return result
}
```

Now check with your date

```
if self.getCurrentDate() == "01.01.2001" {
     \\Your stuff to be added
      print("Date found!!!")
}
```

Comment: DateFormatters should only be used for displaying a human readable date to the user. Not for comparing dates. Please do not use this method.

Comment: According to Appstute, has to compare string which has date with today's date which is in date format so I used above code.

Comment: In this case they should use a date formatted to turn the string into a date and then use Calendar to compare it with another date. Never work with dates as strings.

Comment: `Date()` has `UTC` timezone means when it is `01.01.2001` in your country, it may or may not be the same date in `UTC timeZone`. You should not ignore this and use the `Calendar`'s helper methods as mentioned in @Fogmeister answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dates are complicated... let Apple do it for you... [Calendar date comparison](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292870-isdate)

```
let date1 = // some date
let date2 = // some date

let isSameDay = Calendar.current.isDate(date1, equalTo: date2, toGranularity: .day)
let isSameHour = Calendar.current.isDate(date1, equalTo: date2, toGranularity: .hour)
let isSameMonth = Calendar.current.isDate(date1, equalTo: date2, toGranularity: .month)
```

etc...

This will work no matter which time zone, which calendar type is being used, etc...

Answer (score -2):

compare both date string like,

```
if date1.stringWithFormatter(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd") == Date().stringWithFormatter(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd") {
// today's date
}else{
// not today's date
}

extension Date {

    func stringWithFormatter(dateFormat: String) -> String {
        let formatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
    func datefromString(string:String,dateFormat: String) -> Date {
        let formatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
        return formatter.date(from: string)!
    }

}
```

Comment: DateFormatters should only be used for displaying a human readable date to the user. Not for comparing dates.

Comment: but logically you can get result through this code. i think if you get always right answer from any code then code is correct.

Comment: There are many reasons why this code is not correct. One of which is that it’s using date formatted strings to compare dates.